# rails force execution of SQL query in where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, query-optimization

this is the code that i have:

```
list_views = ListView.where(:user_id => current_user.id)
total_list_views = list_views.size
top_recommended_lists = recommendations_based_on_list_views(list_views, language_score_hash, level_score_hash, category_score_hash)
```

and then there is this method

```
def recommendations_based_on_list_views(list_views, language_score_hash, level_score_hash, category_score_hash)
  viewed_lists_ids = list_views.map {|list_view| list_view.list_id}.uniq
  ....
```

problem is with this code 2 queries are executed on `ListView` model
one at `list_views.size` and then at `list_views.map {|list_view| list_view.list_id}.uniq`

if we can force query execution at `ListView.where(:user_id => current_user.id)` then only single query to `ListView` model will be needed OR if any other way

how to achieve this ??

Answer (score 5):

Found the way to this. We can use `load`:
`list_views = ListView.where(:user_id => current_user.id).load`

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/load